# Tag "not-root-user" as synonym for "non-root-user"

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I have stumbled across two tags which seem to cover exactly the same thing yet only differ by one letter: [non-root-user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-root-user) (42 questions) vs. [not-root-user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/not-root-user) (371 questions).

I have created a [synonym proposal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/non-root-user/synonyms) on [non-root-user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-root-user) because this is where I have the necessary score, but the question would probably be which of the two ones should "survive". *non-root-user* sounds better that *not-root-user* to my ears, but the latter has more questions tagged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag `not-root-user` is now a synonym for `non-root-user`, and existing questions with the synonym have been remapped with the target tag.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with this and would prefer to see [non-root-user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-root-user) as the primary tag.

(posted for voting purposes)

Answer (score -5):

Facts :

To date : 227,373 questions on U&L_SE
100*(42+371)/227373=**.18%**

Adding [Stephen's pertinent observation](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/tag-not-root-user-as-synonym-for-non-root-user#comment12608_6051)

> There are so few users with enough reputation to vote here

---

**Why bother ?**

Too many categories kill the interest of categorizing.
Categorizing out of the possible interaction of possible interested end-users is just : useless (to users).

Therefore : Burn! Burn! Burn!
Which one ?
**BOTH!**

Not to tell my personal opinion that as soon as, about a purely technical matter, whatever question turns to be what ? Lexical ? Syntactical ? Rhetorical ? matter… Well… please… blame me if I sound vulgar : FTS!

Comment: For what it's worth, I have attached this tag (one of them, don't remember which) to questions where the user wants to do something as an ordinary user which usually (or which they think) requires elevated privileges. The tag could be attached to question relating to configuration or package installation questions, for example, where the user does not have root access. I definitely do see some use in keeping one of the tags around.

Comment: @Kusalananda : I of course do not blame you (or any user human being introducing the tags) Aristoteles himself acted more or less identically… for… a limited period of time. ;-)

Comment: If I'm reading you correctly, one of your points is that the volume in the non-root-user & not-root-user tags is small. It's on page 9 **of 81** of the most popular tags, so there could certainly be a good conversation about *when* we want to introduce new tags, but I believe AdminBee's suggestion here *improves* the situation by consolidating two similar tags.

Comment: @JeffSchaller : You indeed read correctly **one** of my **three** points. Based on this one only… I would consequently have written that at least 100*(81-9)/81 percent of the tags should be deleted, I did not, did I ? Moreover, I neither downvoted AdminBee's suggestion nor your answer. Meaning that I do as well believe this could improve the situation. But… only doing… half of the job.